# npm install -g cordova. So many errors. Help please

Tags: node.js, cordova, command-line-interface

I want to develop an app using Cordova(PhoneGap).
I am trying to install cordova using "cordova documentation". 
But i am total noob in these things. I have done these steps:

1. Download and install Node.js
2. Download and install a git client
3. Install the cordova module using npm utility of Node.js.

And at step number 3  i got a lot of errors.

I have typed a command:

> C:>npm install -g cordova

And i have got this as a response:

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bund
led package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
C:\Users\UltimateUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\UltimateUser\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@5.0.0 C:\Users\UltimateUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.6)
└── cordova-lib@5.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0,
 elementtree@0.1.5, rc@0.5.2, d8@0.4.4, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0, dep-graph
@1.1.0, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, plist@1.1.0, glob@4.0.6, npmconf@0.1.16, np
m@1.3.4, cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.5, tar@1.0.2, init-package-json@1.6.0, requ
est@2.47.0, cordova-js@3.9.0)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

Questions:

1. Have there been made any changes, i mean can i repeat the command
   again succesfully or i must "clean" something after this "everything goes wrong" command?
2. I am not using any proxy( though i am not sure about connection, family member was uploading a video on youtube from another device). Could it influence?
3. Is it all because i didn't download SDK. (i am sorry)
4. I was also in "safe mode" + cmd + internet, because my netbook is very old and slow and i am using this mode when i need to speed up. Can it be the reason?

So after all, can i repeat everything (after dowloading sdk and using a connection without any "loadings"). OR before i must clean the mess i have done with previous attempt?

Please help. Don't judge too severely. :)

**UPDATE: After installing SDK, and doing everything outside "safe mode" i have got this:**

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bund
led package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\UltimateUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\UltimateUser\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@5.0.0 C:\Users\UltimateUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.6)
└── cordova-lib@5.0.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.1.0, rc@0.5.2, shel
ljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, d8@0.4.
4, init-package-json@1.6.0, elementtree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, cordo
va-registry-mapper@1.1.5, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-app-hello-world@3.9.0,
 npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@3.9.0)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what safe mode does to Windows, but you should attempt it outside of safe mode just to confirm that's not the only thing causing this issue.

Comment: ok, i have repeated everything without safe mode, also i have downloaded and istalled sdk.

Comment: @Randy , please take a look at UPDATE. what is going wrong now?

Comment: It looks like it succeeded.

Comment: you can safely ignore those WARNings in your last output. Enjoy!

Comment: bund
led package wasn't found in unpacked tree - what does it mean?

Comment: windows is the curfil

Answer (score 4):

i have tha same errore i fix it by updating NPM

```
npm install npm -g
```

i hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating npm? Please update/install npm with admin/root privilege.
Here is the quick command to update npm `npm update [-g]`
For further read, please refer [npm update doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)